# Implementing a custom distance function

Tags: matlab, matrix, distance

`A` and `B` are matrices consisting of binary elements. `A` is denoted as the base data matrix and `B` is the query matrix. `A` consists of 75 data points each of length 10 and `B` consists of 50 data points each of length 10. I want to calculate the distance between all data points in `A` and every query data point in `B` in order to apply nearest neighbor search. So instead of using the Euclidean or the hamming distance, I have used another metric :

[image: metric]

`N = 2`, `k = length of data samples`, `s = A(1,:)` and `t = B(1,:)`.
The code works for one data sample in `A` and another data sample in `B`. How do I scale so that it works for all base data points and all query data points?

## Example for which the code works

Let `A(1,:) = [1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]` is the first sample in A matrix. Let `B(1,:) = [1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0]` is the first query point.

If the elements in samples taken from `A` and B are same, 0 is recorded for each similar element, otherwise 1. The final distance is the sum of the 1's. So the program checks to see if two sequences are the same, setting `b` to 1 if
 so, or a zero otherwise.  Can somebody please show how I can apply this to matrices?

## Code

```
l = length(A);

D=zeros(1,l);
for i=1:l,
    if A(1,i)==B(1,i),
        D(1,i)=0;
    else 
        D(1,i)=1;
    end
end

sum=0;
for j=1:l,
    sum=sum+D(1,j);
end

if sum==0, 
    b = 1;
else 
    b = 0;
end
```

Comment: You mention that your distance metric is not the Hamming distance but the first `for` loop looks like it is similar... can you clarify? The Hamming distance adds up the total number of disagreeing positions between corresponding elements. However, you are calculating the total number of agreeing positions, which is what your first `for` loop is doing. Also, are you saying that this code works between two query vectors and you want to extend to matrices?  I would like to write a more vectorized approach, but if you are bent in using loops I can live with that. Please clarify.

Comment: In the explanation you are saying " If the elements in samples taken from A and B are same, 1 is recorded for each similar element, otherwise zero" but in the code you are doing the opposite

Comment: Please see the edited question where I have put the formula. The code works between one base vector and one query vector. I am asking how I can modify it to work for 75 base vectors and 50 query vectors. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**One line solution**

This calculation can be done in a single line of code:

```
D = A*B'+(1-A)*(1-B)' < size(A,2)
```

**Explanation**

Do to the fact that A and B are binary, the distance function between each sample at A and each sample at B basically checks if the amount of per-coordinates matches is equal to a sample's length.
You can use matrix multiplication to achieve this.

**More descriptive code example**

Define A and B as two binary matrices as you mentioned in your answer:

```
%initializes A and B randomly
A = double(rand(75,10) > 0.5);
B = double(rand(50,10) > 0.5);
[m,n] = size(A);
```

The distance between each sample in A and each sample in B can be calculated as follows:

First, define a matrix D of size 75x50, s.t D(i,j) is contains the number of matches between the sample i in A and the sample j in B.

It can be calculated as follows:

```
D = A*B' + (1-A)*(1-B)';
```

The final distance measure can be done by testing for each pair (i,j) if their amount of matches is smaller than n (n is the length of each sample). If it is smaller the samples are different and the result should be 1. Otherwise it should be zero. this can be done as follows:

```
finalDist = D < n ;
```

Comment: shouldnt it be A.*B?

Comment: @Umar No. You have to sum up all of the agreeing elements together, so matrix-matrix multiplication is very suitable. The code you wrote above is exactly the same as matrix-matrix multiplication, but you are using two sum calls to do it.

Comment: Is this the same distance metric as in the OP? My understanding is that the distance between `[1,0,0,1]` and `[1,1,0,0]` would be `2` because 2 elements differ, however `A*B'` gives a distance of only `1` because it basically finds where both vectors equal `1`?

Comment: @drorco: I ran your code but it throws error : Error using * Both logical inputs must be scalar. TO compute elementwise TIMES, use TIMES (.*) instead. So, based on the error, I used element wise multiplication but then also the error is saying Matrix dimensions must agree. Another thing I noticed is that the distance matrix D must be a 75 by 50 (as explained in your answer) dimension whereas based on your approach I should get 75 by 10

Comment: @Dan - Thank you, you are correct, I modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: @SKM - write A=double(A) and B=double(B) and it will work (the matrices needs to be of type double). also, the size of D is 75 by 50 if you look closely

Comment: One last Question, just to know if my understanding is correct or not. The solution that you mentioned is a vectorized version of the statement :  sum=sum+D(1,j);  I need the formula in the Question and then using your solution, can I find b i.e., how many strings are similar?

Comment: @SKM if you write D = A*B'+(1-A)*(1-B)' < size(A,2), you actually get the final result - the b value for each i,j pair. if you only write D = A*B'+(1-A)*(1-B)' - then it will be the vectorization of the first part (until the loop which contains sum=sum+D(1,j))

Comment: I see, so when I implemented your solution to a large matrix of dimension A = 1million by 960 and B = 1000 by 960, I am getting error = Out of memory bounds. Is this because of using double typecast? How can I apply yur solution so that it works for large dimensional matrices?

Comment: @SKM you can try `uint8` instead of `double` but that is a pretty massive matrix so you might still not have the memory. How much memory does your system have?

Answer (score 2):

Your distance metric is actually just the L1-norm i.e. `sum(abs(x-y))` so *in Octave* you can use [`pdist2`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/statistics/function/pdist2.html) like this:

```
pdist2(A,B,'L1')
```

In MATLAB you can use city block distance:

```
pdist2(A,B,'cityblock')
```

Note, to define your own distance metric (but `'cityblock'` is a better idea):

```
pdist2(A,B,@(x,y)sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus,x,y)),2))
```

Or

```
pdist2(A,B,@(x,y)sum(bsxfun(@xor,x,y),2))
```

Or

```
pdist2(A,B,@(x,y)sum(bsxfun(@ne,x,y),2))
```

---

The distance of one of your vectors with another can be found like this:

```
distance = @(x,y)sum(x~=y)
```

However you want to compare all the row of `A` with all the rows of `B`. `bsxfun` is going to be useful here, we just need to use `permute` to make one of the matrices go into the third dimension:

```
D = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@ne, permute(B, [3,2,1]),A),2))'
```

For example if

```
A = [1,1,0;
     0,0,1;
     1,1,1];

B = [1,1,1;
     0,0,0;
     1,1,1;
     0,1,0]
```

Then

```
> D = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@ne, permute(B, [3,2,1]),A),2))'

D =

   1   2   0
   2   1   3
   1   2   0
   1   2   2
```

So the columns are now the rows of `A` and he rows are the rows of `B` so `D(2,3)` means compare `B(2,:)` (which is `[0,0,0]` with `A(3,:)` which is `[1,1,1]`, and so since all the elements are different, the distance between them is `3`.

If you have the stats toolbox then you can use my `distance` function above with `pdist2` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried working with pdist() as I have the toolbox but that throws error : Error using pdist2 (line 616)
Error evaluating distance function '@(x,y)sum(abs(x-y))'.'  However, the bsxfun works but it is hard to follow especially the permute [3,2,1] command. Could you please let me know how I can apply pdist?

Comment: @SKM I'll try `pdist2` tomorrow. `permute` is just like an n-dimensional version of a transpose. So if transposing a matrix swaps dimensions 1 and 2, then my version of permute is swapping 1 and 3. So `bsxfun` expands on a singelton dimension, i,e, a dimension of size 1, So I used `permute` to make the matrix have only 1 row. So it expands down the rows but also on the new third dimension as matrix `A` has a 'depth' of 1 in the third dimension. Because it is expanding in both these dimensions, it ends up comparing every row in `A` against every row in `B`

Comment: So, if the vector is n dimensional (n=900) then [3,2,1] may not work? Basically, I am getting memory out of bound error using bsxfun for vectors of higher dimension (n)

Comment: @SKM higher dimension... or larger size? You certainly do not have a 900 dimension matrix. This is a 1D matrix: `ones(10,1)` of size `10`. This is a 2D matrix of size `10`-by-`10`: `ones(10,10)` and a 3D matrix of size `10`-by-`10`-by-`10`: `ones(10,10,10)` etc... what are the actual dimensions of the `A` and `B` you are using? Because with `75`-by-`10` I am very surprised by an out of memory error

Comment: By dimensions, I mean the length of each vector where a vector is a feature of some object. I am using 2 databases - iris.mtx and the GIST database. Iris database contains 2 files - the base file that has 150 feature vectors each of dimension 4 and another file is the truth file of same size. Your solution works fine for Iris database.

Comment: The GIST feature database is the one where I am getting the error. It contains several files of N datapoints of N objects. Each datapoint is a feature vector of length 960. I have asked a Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690080/matlab-how-to-get-neighborhood-of-points-in-using-sorting-of-distances . In the QUestion, I am using the Hamming Distance instead of the custom distance since the custom distance throws the out of memory error. Could you please have a look at the Question  I linked, maybe you can better understand what the problem is. Thank you for your continued help.

Comment: @SKM I added the MATLAB `pdist2` solutions. `'cityblock'` distance is equivalent to what you want but I added how to make the L1 metric work as well. It needed a `bsxfun`.

Comment: THank you, I have used the pdist2 with cityblock

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get your code working as is with loops, simply allocate space that is `size(A,1) x size(B,1)` large so that each spatial location `(i,j)` gives you "distance" between rows `i` and `j`.

Therefore, do something like this.  This is assuming that `A` is a `M x d` matrix and `B` is a `N x d` matrix where `d` are the total number of feature points and `M` and `N` are arbitrary positive numbers that denote how many rows of elements there are in each.

```
b = zeros(size(A,1), size(B,1)); % Change
l = size(A,2); % Change - Total number of feature points

for ii = 1 : size(A,1) % Change
    for jj = 1 : size(B,1)
        D=zeros(1,l);
        for i=1:l,
            if A(ii,i)==B(jj,i) % Change
                D(i)=0;
            else 
                D(i)=1;
            end
        end

        sum=0;
        for j=1:l,
            sum=sum+D(j);
        end

        if sum==0, 
            b(ii,jj) = 1; % Change
        end
    end
end
```

This will iterate over all combinations of rows.  However, use any of the previous answers here to get it vectorized. I just wanted to show you how you would modify your current code if this is what you're most comfortable with.

Comment: I think you're missing and `end`. Also a `)` in line 1.

Answer (score 0):

thats what i understood from your description(correct me if I am wrong)
Let A be a matrix

```
A =

     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     1
     1     1     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     1
     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     1     1
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0
     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     0
     1     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0
     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     0
```

and B  be

```
B =

     0     1     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     0
     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     1     1
     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     1
     0     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
     1     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     1
     0     0     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     1
     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     1
>> C = A.*B
```

will give you common points between them if A has more number of row lets say then you can do is `A(1:size(B,1),:).*B` instead

```
C =

     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
     0     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0
     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
```

In the find if there are no matching points b = 1 otherwise 0

```
b = ~find(sum(sum(C)))
```

Update : if D should be 75x50 like you say so then C should be

```
  C = A*(B.')
```

instead of

```
C = A.*B
```

because first i thought its a dot comparison from your code

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But there is a problem with your solution. The matrix C is of primary interest since it is the one in the foruma and which I denote by the variable sum. The C matrix should be 75 by 75 (if A and B are of same size). The reason for C do be of this dimension is that I want to later sort the distance matrix and pick nearest points.

Comment: This is just an exampleof 10 by you can extend it to 75 x 10 and 50 x 10 :) the method would be the same

Comment: should D be 75x50 or 75x75 ?

Comment: The code throws error using .* Matrix dimensions must agree in the line C = A(size(A,1),:).*B

Comment: If A and B are same size then 75*75 else 75*50

Comment: Sorry my bad it should be A(1:size(B,1),:).*B , I have updated now chk